# Не получается узнать количество элементов в HTML коллекции

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такая функция:

```
function clearTable(){
    var tbl = document.getElementById('message_table');
    var trCollection = tbl.getElementsByClassName("message_content_record");

    console.log(trCollection);
}
```

Вот её вывод:

Скриншот 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот 2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

9 элементов как и ожидалось.

Теперь пытаюсь получить это количество:

```
function clearTable(){
    var tbl = document.getElementById('message_table');
    var trCollection = tbl.getElementsByClassName("message_content_record");

    console.log(trCollection.length);
}
```

Вот ее вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим функция та же но при обращении к её свойству получаем **нуль!** (хотя мы знаем что там на самом деле 9 элементов). В чем может быть причина такого неопределенного поведения?

*PS*

Строки в эту таблицу добавляются из скрипта, конфликтов имен нет. JQuery так же не может получить доступ к этим элементам.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `tbl.getElementsByClassName("message_content_record");` использовать `tbl.querySelectorAll(".message_content_record");`

Comment: @greybutton , получаю пустой список в котором length равно нулю

Comment: А можете написать как эта таблица и где генерится? И строчки в том числе.....и в какой момент `clearTable` вызывается

Answer (score -1):

Причина была в том, что строки таблицы добовлялись с помощью AJAX. Ну и естественно что была некоторая задержка при этом. А происходило вот что на самом деле:

1. Создовался пустой объект типа HTMLcollection
2. С какого то перепугу в нем появлялось 9 пустых элементов (мне это
   очень странным кажется)
3. Обращение к несуществующему свойству length из моей функции
4. Происходит загрузка элементов в Объект (HTMLcollection)

Вот так должен выглядеть заполненый элемент HTMLcollection (обратите внимание что у него между скобок):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е нужно поменять пункты 3 и 4 местами. Я это решил с помощью функции setTimeout.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50513/discussion-on-answer-by-perfect-------html).